# The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that will auto-sort the first column of my spreadsheet each time I open it. But I'm getting the error "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:M5000";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How many rows and and columns are in the sheet?

Comment: Your onEdit() function will run on every sheet in your spreadsheet

Comment: 19 rows and an undetermined number of rows. Likely will be less than 1,000. The sheet is updated with a form submission. I want the sheet to auto-sort so the latest submission are on top (Row 2) and descending.

Comment: If this sheet is linked to a form, it's not going to do that..  And the reason for the error is that your range is outside of the limits of the sheet.  In otherwords it's bigger than the sheet.

Comment: You'll be able to sort it if you wish but it will always put the next entry on the bottom.

Comment: Oh and the form submission will not trigger the onEdit() simple triggers only fire on user edits.

Comment: Could you explain again what you meant to write here "19 rows and an undetermined number of rows."? Please, Could you also share a dummy sheet and form or at least how your sheet and form are structure?  So, your end goal is to have a form that when it's submitted the answer will appear at the top (row 2)?